# Autofac register provider for open generic

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have two implementations of a generic interface.

```
public class ConcreteComponent1<T>:IService<T>{}
public class ConcreteComponent2<T>:IService<T>{}
```

I have a factory which will create the proper concrete implementation.

```
public class ServiceFactory
{
    public IService<T> CreateService<T>()
    {
        //choose the right concrete component and create it
    }
}
```

I have a registered the below service consumer which will consume the service.

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(IService<Token> token){}    
}
```

I am not sure how to register a provider for open generic service with autofac. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have a factory which will create the proper concrete implementation." [Don't use a factory; it's a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Answer (score 2):

As @Steven said I would also recommend against using a factory. Instead you could register your `IService<T>` as [named or keyed service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services) and then decide in the constructor of the `Consumer` class which implementation you want to use:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ConcreteComponent1<>)).Named("ConcreteComponent1", typeof(IService<>));
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ConcreteComponent2<>)).Named("ConcreteComponent2", typeof(IService<>));
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Consumer>();
```

Then you can use the `IIndex<K,V>` class to get all the named implementations of your `IService<T>` class:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly IService<Token> _token;

    public Consumer(IIndex<string, IService<Token>> tokenServices)
    {
        // select the correct service
        _token = tokenServices["ConcreteComponent1"];
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to name your services you can also get all available implementations by injecting `IEnumerable<IService<Token>>` and then choose the correct service however you like.